# MS Access - How can I unlink text boxes in a form from their table?

Tags: mysql, sql, forms, ms-access, textbox

I have a form that relates to different products and their feedback. The intention of the form is to add new feedback to `Feedback` table. Present on the form are fields that are currently linked to `Products` table. But I do not want to add anything to the `Products` table, the text fields are just there for reference.

However, when entering data into this form, I am returned with an error asking me to enter data into fields. These fields are controlled with a `DLookup` function. But I do not want to enter data with these fields anyway - they are just for reference.

How can I unlink these text boxes from their table, so that when entering data into this form, the discussed fields are disregarded?

Edit:

[screenshot of form in design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK7j0.png)

This is what my form looks like in design view. I would like the first seven rows to be for user reference only and to have no effect on the `Products` table. The final five rows and fields present in the `Feedback` table - I would like these to be added.

Comment: Make sure your form is bound to the `Feedback` table rather than the `Products` table (set the Record Source property for the form). For the individual controls on the form, you will need one that is bound to the ProductID (or whatever it is in the Feedback table that is used as foreign key to the Products table), but the rest of the product details controls should be unbound (Control Source set to `=DLookup(...)` rather than one of your table's fields). If you're still having trouble, please post more details about your table structures and how your form is configured.

Comment: I have tried setting the control source to only `Feedback` - this gives me `#Name` errors. I have added a screenshot and explanation to my question, maybe it makes more sense? @Skippy

Comment: I just fixed the problem - I am not quite sure what I did. The only change I made was changing the first field you see in the screenshot to `Feedback.productID`