# How can I make it so certain text boxes in a form do not update the table?

Tags: ms-access

I have a form that relates to different products and their feedback. The intention of the form is to add new feedback to the feedback table. But present on the form, are details from the products table. These text boxes are for reference only, and I don't want them to update the table.

For example, when I enter information into the form, and submit it, I will be returned with an error asking me to enter data into fields that don't allow zero length. But I don't want these fields to update the table anyway - as they are just reference. [image: screenshot of form]

Fields from `Products.productID` to `Final Price` are for reference only, and I do not want them to update the table. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Access - How can I unlink text boxes in a form from their table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329337/ms-access-how-can-i-unlink-text-boxes-in-a-form-from-their-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the first field from `Products.productID` to `Feedback.productID`.

This way, this field will be entering `productID` with the `Feedback` table rather than `Products`.

Also, don't forget to change `Products.productID` in the `DLookUp` statements too.